# Oracle APEX Format Mask for Display only Items

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have been bothering with the Display Only Items in APEX for some time now.

[Display Only Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU579.png)

[Page Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeuOq.png)

The Source of this Item is a SQL Query (return single value)

```html
select 
sum(IST_KOSTEN) Anzahl
from OFC_GEM_PLAN_IST
```

But for some reason it dont apply the "Format Mask" for this Item.

This Number is a Currency i want it to Display €832.224,00  (FML999G999G999G999G990D00)

Can someone explain me what i need to do?

Thanks

Best Regards
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply it directly within a query:

```
select to_char(sum(IST_KOSTEN), 'FML999G999G999G999G990D00') Anzahl
from OFC_GEM_PLAN_IST
```

Comment: ohh, didn't think about this... Thank you!

Comment: But why does it not work from the page item atribute?

Comment: For me this didnt work, I want to do format masking for number field ( display only) it get set from other page and first time when it come it look correctly ( example; 4,000) but if I change other field which is effect this field it became ( 3000 etc.)when it change format masking is gone basiclly

Comment: Did you try to put format mask into that item's property as well?